# jQuery Mobile and ajax on load

Tags: json, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

Well I´ve been breaking my head with this problem for some time, I´ve tried tons of solutions online yet none of them work.

What I need is to feed data from a json to a listview on page load and present it yet it only works on index after that I need to reload every page so I can see the listview.

Here´s my jquery code:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
                $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            });
            $(document).bind('pageinit',function() {
                DrawPageContent();
            });

             function DrawPageContent() {
             $.ajax({
                  dataType: "json",
                  url: "js/categorias.json",
                  success: function(msg){
                                console.log(msg.categorias[1].nombre);
                                var categos = '';
                                for(var i=0;i<msg.categorias.length;i++){
                                    categos += '<li><a href="refrescos.html?id='+ 0 +'"><img src="'
                                    + msg.categorias[i].logo + '"><h2>'+msg.categorias[i].nombre
                                    + '</h2><p>' + msg.categorias[i].desc + '</p></a></li> ';
                                }
                                $("#categorias").html(categos);
                                $("#categorias").listview("refresh");
                                //$("#page").trigger("pagecreate");
                            }
                });}
```

I've also tried $(document).ready() and some other things.

Here's the HTML for that part:

```
<div id="page" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Categorias</h1>
        <a href="#popupOpciones" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b" data-transition="pop">Opciones</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="categorias" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        </ul>
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You're loading data on pageinit here, which fires once only.

Comment: My plan here was to make sure that ajax didn't start loading until the page was complete.

Comment: Why don't you use `pagecreate`, or `pagebeforeshow`, or `pageshow`?

Comment: I'll give them a try and report back, thx for the tip.

Comment: I've tried all 3 none seem to work =(

Comment: `mobileinit` is placed in `<head>` after jQuery and before jQuery Mobike?

Comment: @Omar it is inside <head> but after both of them.

Comment: `mobileinit` should be placed after jQuery and before jQuery-Mobile scripts in the head. after that replace all `.bind` with `.on`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to append to the id "categorias" each time that is why it only appends to the first page.

In JQuery mobile the pages that are loaded aren't actually removed from the DOM right away. That means that if you load more than one page that has the and element with id categorias in it, it will end up with multiple DOM elements with categorias identifying them. In this case, it will only append to the first one, which would explain why it is not showing up on your other pages until you refresh and the other pages are removed from the DOM.

A good solution here is to give each page a unique identifier and then select the categorias from that page using

```
$("#categorias", "#pageidentifier");
```

This selector will search within the specific page you specify to find your categorias element.

Comment: Since depending on what the users clicks is the json I load, I've made various htmls each with a unique listview id and page id, all follow the same format as the one above, but once I go to the next html I have to reload to see the listview.

Comment: @Jadager are using the same id for other list views in other pages?

Comment: @Jadager In a similar vein:
Are you loading the pages from an external source?
Or are you using a html string in your program and appending to page container?

Comment: He's using Ajax/JSON data. But this is not the issue as long as data is obtained successfully. Btw, to target a selector based on parent, don't add comma between them i.e. `#foo #bar` u target #bar within #foo.

Comment: No, each list view has it's own id, what I noticed is that ajax doesn't seemed to be called but after the reload.

Comment: @Omar Using Ajax/JSON data doesn't necessitate entirely dynamic pages. He could still be using external pages and appending dynamic content.
As for the selectors, both are valid ways to select an element within a parent.

Comment: @Jadager
Try removing the code bound to mobileinit. I'm not sure dynamic pages will work correctly with AJAX disabled.

Comment: I'll give it a go doing that, had a tempo fix putting everything in one html but is kinda hard to manage a file that big.